# Mac SVN E175002: Could not resolve hostname `'

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion

I'm getting "Could not resolve hostname `' " for any hostname I enter that uses the http/https protocol. No matter what hostname I use it returns the backtick single quote. DNS works fine, I can ping the domain, and navigate to the repo using a browser. I can also browse the repo using TortoiseSVN on a windows machine.

```
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://mysite.com/svnrepo': Could not resolve hostname `': Host not found (http://mysite.com)
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://nonexistantdomain': Could not resolve hostname `': Host not found (http://nonexistantdomain)
```

If I use the svn:// protocol the hostname resolves just fine. I've tried using the svn that ships with Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, SVN from Ports, WANDisco, I even compiled the source and I'm still getting the same thing. I also downloaded serf-1.1.1 and compiled that.

I can't figure out how svn resolves the host name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After trying many things including compiling subversion with both neon and serf I finally figured it out.

~/.subversion/servers

At the end of that file is

```
http-timeout = 
http-proxy-port = 
http-proxy-host = 
http-proxy-username = 
http-proxy-password =
```

I assumed that those equalling nothing ment they were ignored but they are not. After commenting them out, svn can resolve names again.